# Removing existing RO faucet secured with toggle spring butterfly anchors

Tags: faucet

Most RO faucets seem to be held in by a nut, but this one has a butterfly spring anchor type which would have enabled the installer to have tightened/secured it from the top.  I need to install new system but cannot see how to remove the old faucet? The old system is a Watts Premiere wp4.

Comment: A picture or two would nice so we all understand the same thing.

Comment: The answer is excellent, but the question not so much.

Answer (score 3):

I will answer my own question for the benefit of others who might face similar problem. I found that the butterfly or toggle bolt could be removed by removing the water spigot on top and inserting a Philips screwdriver through the opening. Watts install instructions were for a different type of securing nut. Removing the spigot it was necessary to use a bottle jack to pull it out!! [after removal [image: removing]

[image]

In reply to Freeman & Gnicko photo of faucet with toggle bolt attached. Yes it took lots of effort as started out by pulling by hand then hitting with rubber mallet and finally, the jack after soaking overnight with rust penetrating liquid. Maybe that is why Watts now use a nut to lock it in! Obviously I did not care about destroying it as I was replacing it.

Comment: I gotta say... if you needed a 3 ton hydraulic jack to remove that, it strikes me that _something_ was still attached! Either that or it was _very_ severely corroded. Still confused as to where these toggles were, since we've never seen pics of that part of the installation.

Comment: ...and I'm wondering how you were able to use a bottle jack without bending the faucet beyond recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Gut reaction without a picture is "disconnect hose attached to faucet, then turn counterclockwise while pulling up." *i.e.* `"Removal is the reverse of Installation."`